# POSIX Program to search entire file system for a file

Tags: c++, c, posix

Hey everyone. I need to write a POSIX program to search through an entire file system for a specified file starting at the top directory. I've got some code which isn't done at all, but when I run it, and check to see if a particular file is a directory, it's saying this file which is not at all a directory is a directory and is trying to move into it, causing an error. I'm not sure how I can tell it that this type of file isn't a directory.

Here's my code. I know it's not perfect and I could probably do some things differently in the way of getting the directory names and passing them into the function. Either way, I'm pretty sure I have to do this recursively.

The file in question is /dev/dri/card0 and I'm running this from a Debian virtual machine.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

void SearchDirectory(string file_Name, string directory){
    string new_Directory = directory; 
    DIR *dirp; 
    dirp = opendir(directory.c_str()); 
    struct dirent *dptr; 
    struct stat statStruct; 

    while(dptr = readdir(dirp)){
        stat(dptr->d_name, &statStruct); 
        if( S_ISDIR(statStruct.st_mode) ){

            string check = dptr->d_name; 
            if ( check.compare(".") == 0 || check.compare("..") == 0 ){
                continue; 
            }
            else{
                cout << dptr->d_name << " is is a directory" << endl; 
                new_Directory.append("/");
                new_Directory.append(dptr->d_name);  
                SearchDirectory(file_Name, new_Directory); 
            }
        }
        else if( S_ISREG(statStruct.st_mode)){
            string check = dptr->d_name; 
            if( check.compare(file_Name) == 0){
                cout << "Found " << file_Name << " in " << directory << "/" << endl; 
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    if(argc < 2 || argc > 2){
        cerr << "This program will find the specified file." << endl; 
        cerr << "Usage: mysearch <filename>" << endl; 
        return 1; 
    }

    string file_Name = argv[1]; 
    SearchDirectory(file_Name, "/"); 

    return 0; 

}
```

Comment: Also, [nftw](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html), though that's XSI instead of POSIX base.

Comment: @ikegami -- I don't think he is searching for card0. I think he means that S_ISDIR for /dev/dri/card0 is true,  but opendir("/dev/dri/card0") fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->d_name` returns just the name of the file, not the path to the file. You need to stat (not yet constructed) `new_Directory` instead of `dptr->d_name`.

You also have a problem if a directory contains more than one subdirectories. Your construction of `new_Directory` is incorrect for each subdirectory after the first.

You never `closedir` your directory handle, so you run out of resources. You should  also consider loading the entire directory into an array before recursing to avoid running out of handles.

```
void SearchDirectory(string directory, string target_File_Name){
    DIR *dirp = opendir(directory.c_str());
    if (!dirp) {
        perror(("opendir " + directory).c_str());
        return;
    }

    struct dirent *dptr;
    while(dptr = readdir(dirp)){
        string file_Name = dptr->d_name;
        string file_Path = directory + "/" + file_Name;

        struct stat statStruct; 
        stat(file_Path.c_str(), &statStruct); 
        if( S_ISDIR(statStruct.st_mode) ){
            if ( file_Name.compare(".") == 0 || file_Name.compare("..") == 0 ){
                continue; 
            }

            SearchDirectory(file_Path, target_File_Name);
        }
        else if( S_ISREG(statStruct.st_mode)){
            if( file_Name.compare(target_File_Name) == 0){
                cout << file_Path << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    closedir(dirp);
}
```

**Update**: Added second problem.

**Update**: Added third problem.

**Update**: Added code.

Comment: Or you can use `fstatat` to avoid having to assemble strings (and the associated race conditions in the directory structure).

Answer (score 4):

POSIX.2 requires a working "find" command.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>", argv[0]);
    }

    execlp("find", "find", "/", "-name", argv[1], "-print", (char *)NULL);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not for the benefit of the OP, who writes "The point is to come up with a way to do it myself," but rather for the benefit of posterity, here is a way to use [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm):

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

// sample usage: find_file("/home", ".profile");
void find_file( const fs::path& dirPath, const std::string& fileName) {
  fs::recursive_directory_iterator end;
  for(fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(dirPath); it != end; ++it) {
    if(it->leaf() == fileName)
      std::cout << it->path() << "\n";
    if(fs::is_symlink(it->symlink_status()))
      it.no_push();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `fork`, `execv` and the Unix implemented /usr/bin/find process and redirect its output for your result area?

Comment: I can't. The point is to come up with a way to do it myself :P Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's POSIX or not but the nftw library function is widely available on UNIX (HP-UX, AIX, Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is "search a tree for a match"

BFS and DFS are the canonical basic algorithms. Give them a start node and go.

You will get into trouble if you follow symlinks; so test for them and don't follow them.

You should be able to map each point in the *FS algorithms to a directory operation.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++ is an option, why not use something like [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)?  The [Boost.Filesystem two-minute tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm#tutorial) gives an example of how to implement your search using [directory iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-template-basic_directory_iterator).